# Using Inclusion Exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> How many integer solutions are there to the inequality $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4\lt184$$with $y_1\gt0$, $0\lt y_2\le10$, $0\le y_3\le17$, and $0\le y_4\le 19$?

How do we solve this using Incl. Excl. Principle?

I can see it clearly using Generating Function

Comment: Did you mean to mix strict and non-strict orders?

Comment: I gave you a very large hint in [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/522100/12042) to [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/522078/12042). I don’t think that I can say much more than that without simply doing the problem for you, which I’m not willing to do — especially since I **did** already completely solve a similar problem for you.

Comment: @copper.hat: Yes: it’s a scanned image of the source of the question. I imagine that whoever posed the question wanted to force the student to deal with a few minor complications.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I solved it. I just wanted to check the answer. I am sorry.

Comment: "I solved it. I just wanted to check the answer." Then show what you did--otherwise how to check that it is correct?

Comment: @infinity it's good that you solved it and want to check, just post that and more people will be willing to say if you made a mistake or not

Answer (score 3):

Here is one tedious way:
$S=\sum_{i_4=0}^{18} \sum_{i_3=0}^{17} \sum_{i_2=1}^{10} (183-(i_2+i_3+i_4))$.

This works because $18+17+10 < 183$.

Since I need to procrastinate on some urgent but even more tedious work...

\begin{eqnarray}
S &=& 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 10 \cdot 183
-19\cdot 18 \sum_{i_2=1}^{10} i_2
-19 \cdot 10 \sum_{i_3=0}^{17} i_3
- 18 \cdot 10 \sum_{i_4=0}^{18} i_4 \\
&=& 625860
- 342 \sum_{i_2=1}^{10} i_2
-190 \sum_{i_3=1}^{17} i_3
- 180 \sum_{i_4=1}^{18} i_4 \\
&=& 625860
- 342 \frac{1}{2}10 \cdot 11
-190 \frac{1}{2}17 \cdot 18
- 180 \frac{1}{2}18 \cdot 19\\ \\
&=& 547200
\end{eqnarray}
(Assuming I calculated correctly.)