# Number of ways to put $n$ indistinguishable objects into $k$ distinguishable various-size bins

Tags: combinatorics

[Similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89417/number-of-ways-to-put-n-unlabeled-balls-in-k-bins-with-a-max-of-m-balls-in) have been asked before, however in this case each of the bins may each have a different capacity. Example: There are $2$ possibilities to put $7$ objects into two bins of the size $5$ and $3$, respectively. Is there a formula that will result in the amount of ways this can be done given the number of objects and the bin sizes?

PS: I've already come up with a way on how to brute force this by simply checking all possible combinations and counting the valid ones. I was just wondering if there was an easier way to approach this.

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203835/enumerating-number-of-solutions-to-an-equation) gives a complete solution to a concrete numerical problem in which the sizes are all the same. My answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522078/inclusion-exclusion) shows what modifications are necessary when the sizes are not all the same.

Comment: Too bad there's no way to upvote a comment, you pointed me on the right track and I managed to solve the problem.

Comment: @LeoTietz I have the same problem - did you find a closed formula solution for the general problem? If so do you mind sharing it?

Answer (score 0):

X1 + X2 + X3 ...... + Xk= n 
(Where Xi is number of objects in the ith bin )
We need to find the number of non negative integral solutions of this equation . Which is 
(n+k-1)C(k-1)

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but could you provide an example for how to use this (maybe using the example in my post)?

Comment: Yeah sure . Say you are given 10 identical balls and you have to put them in 3 identical bins . So you can apply (n+k-1)C(k-1) where n= 10 k=3 so we'll get 12C2

Comment: How would it work for my example? (7 objects, 2 bins of size 7 and 3)?